# Сколько времени должна восстанавливаться полная копия SQL Server, если известно время её создания?

Tags: sql-server, резервное-копирование

Есть полная копия БД SQL Server , она создавалась 8.5 часов, и занимает 1.4 Тб. Подскажите пожалуйста на какое время мне рассчитывать при восстановлении из этой копии, на такую же машину? Если нет точной зависимости, то может хотя бы порядок (например х2 или х3), это нужно для планирования времени перемещения БД.

Comment: Вряд ли кто вам такое скажет. Вы попробуйте сами восстановить. Это по-хорошему всё-равно нужно попробовать сделать. Не только чтобы время узнать, но и чтобы проверить процесс. У меня в практике бывали случаи, когда бэкапы делались, но когда настал их час, выяснилось, что бэкапы были битые и восстановить из них ничего нельзя ))  Так что в идеале это нужно даже не один раз проверить, а делать такое восстановление на резервный сервер регулярно.